# Creating media.Image from raw byte arrays

Tags: android, android-ndk, buffer

Currently I have all planes data of an image which is in the form of byte array.
Is it possible to construct a media.Image from the available data?

I see media.Image and media.Image.Plane classes are both abstract and unable to extend them.

How can we create a media.Image instance from raw image channel buffers?

Answer (score 0):

This class allows for efficient direct application access to the pixel data of the Image through one or more ByteBuffers. Each buffer is encapsulated in a Plane that describes the layout of the pixel data in that plane. Due to this direct access, and unlike the **Bitmap** class, Images are not directly usable as UI resources.

Comment: Then how to create it?